# Customtkinter and pyinstaller issue

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, customtkinter

I am trying to use `pyinstaller` to convert my code to an `.exe` but when I run the command

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --name Pendu --onedir --icon=icon.ico --add-data "C:\Users\adamc\OneDrive\onda\envs\converter\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter;./customtkinter"  --add-data "C:\Users\adamc\OneDrive\onda\envs\converter\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\assets\themes\green.json" test.pyw
```

I got an error `:pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'C:\\Users\\adamc\\OneDrive\\onda\\envs\\converter\\Lib\\site-packages\\customtkinter\\assets\\themes\\green.json'`

The problem is that my `--add-data` for green.json is crucial else when I run the app I got the customtkinter error saying that some file like json theme file were missing. What can I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the --add-data argument in pyinstaller, you should tell what file / folder to add and then where to add it (separated by ;).

You can replace the second -add-data by:

```
--add-data "C:\Users\adamc\OneDrive\onda\envs\converter\Lib\site packages\customtkinter\assets\themes\green.json;green.json"
```

The full command is now:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --name Pendu --onedir --icon=icon.ico --add-data "C:\Users\adamc\OneDrive\onda\envs\converter\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter;./customtkinter"  --add-data "C:\Users\adamc\OneDrive\onda\envs\converter\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\assets\themes\green.json;green.json" test.pyw
```